# Is there an equivalent to JsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling for XML serialization during Web API request handling?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xml-deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm working on an **ASP.NET Web API** that allows **XML and JSON formats** for its resources. The resource model type for one of my Web API services has a property that users would not send. But I have to set it in response that I send back.

*For example, there is a POST request where users would like to save a new item to database. And my service responds with the same resource model and an additional property indicating it is saved.*

I have added this additional property to my resource model. When I test it in Fiddler passing an XML request, it is complaining with a `HTTP400` saying the new property is missing. With JSON input, it is working fine, probably due to the default JSON setting `JsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling`.

> Do we have an equivalent property to this for XML de-serialisation?

Sample input XML:

```
<MyResource>
    <Property1>ABC</Property1>
    <Property2>DEF</Property2>
</MyResource>
```

Sample output XML that I intend to send:

```
<MyResource>
    <Property1>ABC</Property1>
    <Property2>DEF</Property2>
    <Id>123</Id>    
</MyResource>
```

Error looks like:

```
The property Id was missing
```

My Resource model looks like:

```
public string Property1 { get; set; }
public string Property2 { get; set; }
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's "[JSON and XML Serialization in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter)" page has this to say about XML serialization (under the XML Serialization heading):

> If you need more control over the serialization, you can decorate the class with the **DataContract** attribute. When this attribute is present, the class is serialized as follows:
>
> - "Opt in" approach: Properties and fields are not serialized by default. To serialize a property or field, decorate it with the **DataMember** attribute

The DataMember attribute has the following [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.isrequired(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **IsRequired**
> Gets or sets a value that instructs the serialization engine that the member must be present when reading or deserializing.

So, from documentation, it would appear that decorating your Id property with `[DataMember(IsRequired=false)]` would allow the XML Serializer to allow it to remain at its default value.

Note, though, that the default value is 0, so you'll need to check explicitly for that value as the "no value" marker. If you want to logically differentiate between an entity with ID=0 and an entity with *no* ID, consider changing its type to `int?`, so the default value would be `null`.

Comment: I have decorated the model with `DataContract` and the property with `DataMember(IsRequired = false)`. Still getting the same error. Trying to dig into my media type formatter settings to see if I need to tweak something there.